# url rewrite when only parameter is on left and we need multiple on right

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website in PHP and I am doing url rewrite using htaccess.

My current URL is

http://www.website.com/product.php?view=iYIDziy4kG

> iYIDziy4kG = unique key

I want to make it like

http://www.website.com/product/category/sub-catgeory/product-name/iYIDziy4kG

I have made rule like this

> RewriteRule    products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) product.php?view=$1 [L]

and when I use

```
print_r($_REQUEST)
```

then it is picking unique key "iYIDziy4kG" in first (.*) but as per my requirements, it should be in last (.*)

what could be the possible solution in this case?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around the first 3 .*

Comment: Or change $1 to $4

Comment: @BenCummins Thanks a lot. It worked. Please add a solution below so that I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the parenthesis around the first three parameters or change $1 to $4.